# Why can the second for loop argument not be equal to number?

Tags: php

I get this: `Fatal error: Out of memory`:

```
    <?php
    // Create an array and push 5 elements on to it, then 
    // print the number of elements in your array to the screen
$numbers = array(1,2,3);

for($i=4;$i=8;$i++){
    array_push($numbers,$i);
}
    print count($numbers);
    ?>
```

But if I change `$i=8` to `$i<9` it works.

What's up with that?

Comment: You are using an assignment `=`, what you want to do is a comparison `==`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` loop is wrong.

```
           v
for($i=4;$i=8;$i++){
```

You're setting `$i` as `8` instead of comparing it to `8`.

To compare values, you must use `==`

```
for($i=4;$i==8;$i++){
```

Also, to clarify, you're getting the error "out of memory" because the loop is running infinitely, which is causing your application to use all available space in memory, causing it to break.

Comment: ohhh okay, I see what you mean

Comment: Yeah, that's a common mistake. I used to do this all the time when I was learning programming and I must admit some times I still do this.

Comment: We first set it to a number but after we compare it...yea, that makes sense

Comment: ``To compare values, you must use ==`` what is with ``<`` ``>`` ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can trie to put to equal instead of one, like "==".

Hope it helps.