# Why is this code not printing random numbers inside a loop

Tags: php

I am trying to print/echo random numbers for 100 times

```
 <?php
  // Write your for loop below!
  for($i=1;$i==100;$i++){
  echo rand(1,5);
  }
  ?>
```

I am not getting any errors either. Whats wrong with this code?

Comment: The condition ``$i == 100`` is false it should be ``$i <= 100``

Comment: @jmattheis Why?

Comment: Yes, One person give the correct information so go with @jmattheis.

Comment: @BitByBit The loop executes as long as the condition is true. `$i == 100` is not true when the loop starts, so it doesn't execute.

Comment: @BitByBit You have a backward understanding of how the condition works. It's not the test for when the loop should stop, it's the test for when the loop should keep repeating.

Comment: The random numbers are irrelevant, you'd have the same problem with `echo "foo";`

Comment: @Barmar That makes more sense. Thanx.

Comment: @Barmar I didn't understand because I asked this question yesterday: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40008544/why-can-the-second-for-loop-argument-not-be-equal-to-number/40008581#40008581]) and was given a wrong answer I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrongly using "for" loop.

Here is manual with examples for it:

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Second expression in for loop is telling "perform instructions if expression is true", so You need change it to something like

```
for($i=1;$i<=100;$i++)
```

in Youre case.

Comment: But yesterday I was given wrong information (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40008544/why-can-the-second-for-loop-argument-not-be-equal-to-number/40008581#40008581)  and it got 2 upvotes so I thought it was correct.

Comment: @BitByBit I think this guy meant that "=" and "==" are different operators. "=" will assign value to variable, "==" will compare it.

Comment: Its not "wrong", it is a valid for loop with == but it will not get executed cause the condition is false

Answer (score 2):

You should re-do your code, something like this:

```
<?php
    // Write your for loop below!
    for($i=1; $i<=100; $i++){
        echo rand(1,5) . "<br>";
    }
?>
```